# create table with column age category (18-34, 35-49, 50-64, 65+)

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table with age category (18-34, 35-49, 50-64, 65+). 
I want another column age and when I will insert the age then the age category will show in which category it  will be.
e.g if I insert 18 in age column then age category should show 18-34.
if have tried hard but I cannot find anything that will work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound to me like something a column should do - this sounds like 'business logic'. In the event that the age category criteria changed - unlikely as this may seem - the data in the table would need to be updated with the new categories. I would suggest using something dynamic to determine the category - like a view, or a computed column - then you can still query the data by category, and if the categories change then it's as simple as updating the dynamic category definition.

Now you might say to this "but the categories will never change" and that may be true, but perhaps the reason you have been unable to define a column to hold this information is because this operation is just unsuited to a column. I'm not saying it isn't possible, just that there are better ways of doing it.

Something like this computed column example would be a start - it could just as easily be a view though. Please excuse syntax errors, as I don't have access to a SQL server right now.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Example(
    Age integer,
    AgeCategory AS 
        CASE
            WHEN Age < 18 THEN '<18'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 18 and 34 THEN '18-34'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 35 and 49 THEN '35-49'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 and 64 THEN '50-64'
            WHEN Age > 64 THEN '65+'
        END
)
```

Personally I would want to avoid using '18-34' as the column value, just in case it were to change, but right now I can't think of a better one..

Answer (score 1):

As @sturard suggests, you should use a lookup table for this, populated with all the possible ages.  Then JOIN it whenever you need to get the category for an age.  eg

```
use tempdb 

go
CREATE TABLE AgeCategory(
    Age int primary key,
    AgeCategory AS 
        CASE
            WHEN Age < 18 THEN '<18'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 18 and 34 THEN '18-34'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 35 and 49 THEN '35-49'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 and 64 THEN '50-64'
            WHEN Age > 64 THEN '65+'
        END persisted
)

insert into AgeCategory(Age) 
select top 150 row_number() over (order by (select null))
from sys.messages
```